Can't launch my Spring Boot App after adding some database options
I started getting this error after trying to connect my Spring Boot application to an Oracle DB. This was running completely fine before and I could bring up my main page and navigate between pages and submit a form to create a java object but now I can't even run it.
I tried to remove all the references to the database connection but that doesn't seem to help. I have no clue what the issue is. I looked on hear and saw a bunch of other answers talking about adding various dependencies but none of them worked out.
I'm an amateur programmer so it is likely that I overlooked something very simple. Any help is greatly appreciated!
The Error:
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=+BjRCnJgT3uBCvSq3SCIaQ==)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:902) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:707) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1094) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:89) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:732) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:648) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:342) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:168) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:118) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:87) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:80) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:143) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.philosophy.plato.PlatoApplication.main(PlatoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=+BjRCnJgT3uBCvSq3SCIaQ==)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:715) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:584) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:964) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:350) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:2627) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:666) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:436) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:393) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketEngine(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:359) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.newSSLEngine(TcpsNTAdapter.java:658) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:255) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:230) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.executeConnOption(ConnStrategy.java:1014) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:673) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the key store.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:710) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:410) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: SSO not found
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:873) ~[na:na]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyStoreInstance(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:924) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:1059) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:694) ~[ojdbc11-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:870) ~[na:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted


My POM.XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.philosophy.plato</groupId>
    <artifactId>Plato</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Plato</name>
    <description>Plato</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


My Application.properties file:
When I input the database info into intellij's build in DB connection system and test the connection, it works. But my program doesn't.
spring.application.name=Plato
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@socratesdb_high?TNS_ADMIN=C:/Wallet_SocratesDB
spring.datasource.username=XXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXX
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

My Controller:
package com.philosophy.plato.controllers;

import com.philosophy.plato.objects.Employee;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String landing() {
        return "html/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/demographic")
    public String goToDemographic(Model model) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);

        List<String> prefixList = Arrays.asList(" ", "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Miss", "Dr.", "Rev.", "Sr.");
        model.addAttribute("prefixList", prefixList);

        List<String> ethnicityList = Arrays.asList(" ", "American Indian", "Alaskan Native", "Asian", "Black", "Hispanic", "Pacific Islander", "White");
        model.addAttribute("ethnicityList", ethnicityList);

        List<String> hispanicOrLatinoList = Arrays.asList(" ", "Y", "N");
        model.addAttribute("hispanicOrLatinoList", hispanicOrLatinoList);

        List<String> statesList = Arrays.asList(
                " ",
                "AK - Alaska",
                "AL - Alabama",
                "AR - Arkansas",
                "AS - American Samoa",
                "AZ - Arizona",
                "CA - California",
                "CO - Colorado",
                "CT - Connecticut",
                "DC - District of Columbia",
                "DE - Delaware",
                "FL - Florida",
                "GA - Georgia",
                "GU - Guam",
                "HI - Hawaii",
                "IA - Iowa",
                "ID - Idaho",
                "IL - Illinois",
                "IN - Indiana",
                "KS - Kansas",
                "KY - Kentucky",
                "LA - Louisiana",
                "MA - Massachusetts",
                "MD - Maryland",
                "ME - Maine",
                "MI - Michigan",
                "MN - Minnesota",
                "MO - Missouri",
                "MS - Mississippi",
                "MT - Montana",
                "NC - North Carolina",
                "ND - North Dakota",
                "NE - Nebraska",
                "NH - New Hampshire",
                "NJ - New Jersey",
                "NM - New Mexico",
                "NV - Nevada",
                "NY - New York",
                "OH - Ohio",
                "OK - Oklahoma",
                "OR - Oregon",
                "PA - Pennsylvania",
                "PR - Puerto Rico",
                "RI - Rhode Island",
                "SC - South Carolina",
                "SD - South Dakota",
                "TN - Tennessee",
                "TX - Texas",
                "UT - Utah",
                "VA - Virginia",
                "VI - Virgin Islands",
                "VT - Vermont",
                "WA - Washington",
                "WI - Wisconsin",
                "WV - West Virginia",
                "WY - Wyoming");
        model.addAttribute("stateList", statesList);

        return "html/employeeEntry";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addEmployee")
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        System.out.println(employee);
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
        return "html/index";
    }
}


And my object that I want to save, I need to re-add the @Entity and @Id annotations
package com.philosophy.plato.objects;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Employee {

    private int idNum; // either entered as text or generated by button, required and unique
    private String namePrefix; // drop down
    private String nameFirst; // text entry
    private String nameMiddle; // text entry
    private String nameLast; // text entry
    private String sex; // radio button
    private String ethnicity; // drop down
    private String hispanicOrLatino; // drop down
    private String address; // text entry
    private String city; // text entry
    private String state; // drop down
    private String zipCode;  // text entry
    private Date dateBirth; // YYYYMMDD
    private Date dateStart; // YYYYMMDD
    private String jobTitle; // text entry

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(int idNum, String namePrefix, String nameFirst, String nameMiddle, String nameLast, String sex, String ethnicity, String hispanicOrLatino, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode, Date dateBirth, Date dateStart, String jobTitle) {
        this.idNum = idNum;
        this.namePrefix = namePrefix;
        this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
        this.nameMiddle = nameMiddle;
        this.nameLast = nameLast;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
        this.hispanicOrLatino = hispanicOrLatino;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
        this.dateStart = dateStart;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getNamePrefix() {
        return namePrefix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "idNum=" + idNum +
                ", namePrefix='" + namePrefix + '\'' +
                ", nameFirst='" + nameFirst + '\'' +
                ", nameMiddle='" + nameMiddle + '\'' +
                ", nameLast='" + nameLast + '\'' +
                ", sex='" + sex + '\'' +
                ", ethnicity='" + ethnicity + '\'' +
                ", hispanicOrLatino='" + hispanicOrLatino + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
                ", dateBirth=" + dateBirth +
                ", dateStart=" + dateStart +
                ", jobTitle='" + jobTitle + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getIdNum() {
        return idNum;
    }

    public void setIdNum(int idNum) {
        this.idNum = idNum;
    }

    public void setNamePrefix(String namePrefix) {
        this.namePrefix = namePrefix;
    }

    public String getNameFirst() {
        return nameFirst;
    }

    public void setNameFirst(String nameFirst) {
        this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
    }

    public String getNameMiddle() {
        return nameMiddle;
    }

    public void setNameMiddle(String nameMiddle) {
        this.nameMiddle = nameMiddle;
    }

    public String getNameLast() {
        return nameLast;
    }

    public void setNameLast(String nameLast) {
        this.nameLast = nameLast;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Date getDateBirth() {
        return dateBirth;
    }

    public void setDateBirth(Date dateBirth) {
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
    }

    public Date getDateStart() {
        return dateStart;
    }

    public void setDateStart(Date dateStart) {
        this.dateStart = dateStart;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getEthnicity() {
        return ethnicity;
    }

    public void setEthnicity(String ethnicity) {
        this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
    }

    public String getHispanicOrLatino() {
        return hispanicOrLatino;
    }

    public void setHispanicOrLatino(String hispanicOrLatino) {
        this.hispanicOrLatino = hispanicOrLatino;
    }
}



In your dependencies (pom.xml file), you have an entry for the oracle dependency with the scope of runtime - e.g. <scope>runtime</scope> - this scope has a meaning; are you sure you want that?  can you comment out (or remove) this from the pom.xml file and try it?

The error
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.

is because you don't have
<groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
<artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>

in your dependencies.

Thank you so much. I had at one point added one of the security dependencies that I had from another project that was working, but that didn't do anything so I was confused. This worked so I appreciate your help!
